# Facebook Signed Request empty after reload

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps

I have a probleme with my Signed Request on my facebook application. The first time is good, and i know if the user like or not my app. But when I reload the application (link, form, like) i loose the Signed Request, (only refresh [F5], and unlike works)..

I realy don't understand why ??

*Links don't work anymore :(*

- This is my test page : https://www.facebook.com/pages/TestCactOos/255835411190164
- And the test app : https://www.facebook.com/pages/TestCactOos/255835411190164?sk=app_335457189856398

On app, you can see $facebook, $_REQUEST and $_SERVER informations.

Thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signed request is in the header of the referral from Facebook. It's not maintained from link to link, since the subsequent referrals will be from your own pages. Use the signed_request to get some info and keep that in your session between pages.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i realy need this information on all page (for know if user like or unlike)

Comment: So fetch that data, put it in your session parameters server-side, and use them on each subsequent page

Answer (score 1):

You are just one time able to get the signed_request. That is exactly when Facebook loads your App in an iframe. Then you must have to save the signed_request for further usage (subpages). There you have to check for the data via $_REQUEST or fall back to your stored signed_request values.
Here is an small example of the fbHelper component. I hope this might give you some ideas how to handle the issue:

Source: http://www.facebook.com/HelperComponentlCommunity/app_412923142052609

```
    if(array_key_exists('signed_request', $_REQUEST))
        $signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
    elseif(array_key_exists('signed_request' . $this->pageId, $_SESSION))
        $signed_request = $_SESSION['signed_request' . $this->pageId];
    else
        return false;

    $facebook_data= $this->parse_signed_request($signed_request);
```